# How would I track price items from different stores over time?

Tags: mysql, database-design, best-practices

I am trying to design a database for a price comparison application, where I get data from different stores of a similar products, so my database needs to compare a price of the same product from different stores and also  track the price trends of a product in a specific store over time.

I am using mysql in building the db.

I need help with the design of the database so that my database will be easy to maintain when it scales up with data, insights of all best practice suggestions are also welcome.

Below is the designs I have done where I have three tables which is Product, Price and Store on the first design, on the second design I have two tables which are Products and Store, I'm just unsure whether I should create Prices as fields in the product table or I should create Price as a table, so that I can keep track of a product's price history and to avoid redundancy.

**First Design**
[image]

**Second Design**
[image]

Comment: Haven't you asked that same (or very, very similar) question on Stackoverflow lately? I remember answering/comment such a question. You seem to have delete it, as I cannot find it anymore. But you should still be able to access it and the answer/comment there still stands also for this version of the question.

Comment: Oh wait, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456076/price-comparison-database-put-price-data-in-main-table-in-one-separate-table#comment115723360_65456076 But the other question probably isn't from you too, I take that back. It'll may help though, it seems like a very, very similar problem.

Comment: Thanks @sticky bit the link is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a separate `PriceHistory` table is better from a [**normalization**](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) standpoint.

But some ERP systems do additionally store the active / current `Price` on the `Products` table too. Up to you how you want to split it, but a dedicated `PriceHistory` table with an `IsActive` or `IsLatest` field for explicity makes the most sense.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with the second option of having  a price table

Comment: @PHULUSOGOVERNRAMULIFHO No problem! If you have any other questions, feel free, and I'll do my best to answer them. (Also feel free to upvote or mark the answer as accepted so other users with similar questions see it was verified as helpful.)